# Forecasting using ClickHouse

Tags: sql, forecasting, clickhouse

I'm using ClickHouse database and I have a table with internal searches data.

```
date      |search_term  |clicks|impresions |
----------|-------------|------|-----------|
2020-06-21|search term 1|2     |129        |
2020-06-21|search term 2|12    |529        |
2020-06-21|search term 3|21    |1129       |

2020-06-22|search term 1|2     |111        |
2020-06-22|search term 2|3     |89         |
2020-06-22|search term 3|28    |2429       |

2020-06-23|search term 1|4     |529        |
2020-06-23|search term 2|0     |10         |
2020-06-23|search term 3|23    |239        |
```

I want get forecasting and get clicks estimations

```
future date|search_term  |clicks|impresions |
-----------|-------------|------|-----------|
2020-06-24 |search term 1|4     |564        |
2020-06-24 |search term 2|0     |15         |
2020-06-24 |search term 3|23    |321        |
```

Can I get forecasting using [simpleLinearRegression](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/simplelinearregression/) for each search term?

Any other "simple" suggestions using ClickHouse? Thanks!

Comment: simpleLinearRegression just gives the *a* and *b* coefficients for linear function *y=ax + b* that cannot describe your case because it is multi-dimensional : there are a huge count of factors/features that could affect the result - day of week, holiday/not holiday, country, gender, age, etc Maybe make sense look at [stochasticLinearRegression](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/stochasticlinearregression/), [CH & Catboost](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/guides/apply-catboost-model/).

Comment: I want a solution "easy". Using this data (I've more of 30 millions data rows) I know that is posible, You can view forecasting using same data, 
https://mark.shinyapps.io/searchConsoleRDemo/

Comment: Only one presentation what I know about forecasting in clickhouse, https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-presentations/raw/master/meetup38/forecast.pdf, sorry it's in Russian, but you can try translate it via deepl.com and pdf to docx online converters

Comment: Thanks @Slach Looks like exactly what I need, besides learning Russian :D